# database file does not appear under data/data/packagename/databases or anywhere else

Tags: android, sqlite

First I have been searching for a solution for acouple of days now. It is very strange as the answer to my problem maybe very simple.

I am trying to make the simplest code to create sqlite database. there is plenty of examples in the web. the code does not generate any error and the application appears on the device. but when I try to locate the database in the specified location as in the title it does not seem to be created.

my specific questions

1-does the device has to be rooted to create a database file.

2-do I need special manualy entered permissions in the manifest file to create the database file.

3-Is there any prior settings that I have to do in android studio or a plug-in that I have to add.

4-Do I have to create the sub folders manualy because some devices dont even have the second data subdirectory of the main data directory in the main internal storage. Any way I created the folders and subfolders but no database appeared after running the application. I use a file explorer in the target device to inspect the existance of the database file.

many thanks for any attempts to help me as I seem to be stuck for few days now.

Answer (score 1):

I found the files in the internal device memory using a root explorer.

The strange thing I have not seen any tutorial which alerts me to the hidden memory and root explorer. time wasted but along the way I learned many new things.

thanks all

Comment: You can also access the database file in an emulator, or using USB debugging on a (non-rooted) phone.